# Update value in UITableViewCell from another methd iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have method called

```
- (void)redeemOfferService
{
  // in this method i want access OffersBoughtCellTableViewCell,
      how to access tableview cell here ?
  // want to update selected tableview cell values
  // here i am getting selected cell details in selectedOfferBoughtObj which 
     is actually NSObject in that i am having five string values  
     i want show that values in my tableview cell how can i ?
  //

}
```

The above method is calling from

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if(alertView.tag == 10)
    {
       if(buttonIndex == 0)
       {
        [self redeemOfferService];
       }
    }
}
```

and this method is calling when i tap on tableview cell i.e.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIAlertView *logoutAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Are you sure you want to redeem?" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
    logoutAlert.tag  = 10;
    [logoutAlert show];
}
```

i know there is way, we can send sender from button click but i want in above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global  variable in your class **NSIndexPath** type and on selected store your selected indexpath

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath; //declare it as a global
```

After assign selected value in didSelect

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UIAlertView *logoutAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Are you sure you want to redeem?" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
logoutAlert.tag  = 10;
[logoutAlert show];
selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

And change like this in your function

```
    - (void)redeemOfferService
{
     OffersBoughtCellTableViewCell * _selectedCell = [offersTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath]; //Now Its your selected cell Try this . 

}
```

It will work fine try once and revert back

Comment: OffersBoughtCellTableViewCell this is my cell and offersTableView this is my tableview, can u explain me  UITableViewCell * _selectedCell = [tableViewObject cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];

Comment: Try like this .. I Updated

Comment: yup.., i tried but its giving me error " incompatible pointer types initializing  OffersBoughtCellTableViewCell* with an expression of UITableviewCell*"

Comment: values are showing temporarily.. when i am  scrolling then updated values are not showing its showing from cellforrowattindexpath how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are surely updating the tableview from some `NSMutableArray`, meaning you are filling up your tableview with this array.

In your `redeemOfferService` method, change the value of that Object inside the `NSMutableArray` with which you are filling up the tableview.
Then call `[self.tableviewName reloadData]`

Comment: i followed as Jogendra.Com was saying ..but now facing ...values are showing temporarily.. when i am  scrolling then updated values are not showing its showing from cellforrowattindexpath how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `indexPathForSelectedRow` property of `UITableView` to access selected indexPath.

```
- (void)redeemOfferService
{
     OffersBoughtCellTableViewCell *selectedCell = (OffersBoughtCellTableViewCell *)[tableViewObject cellForRowAtIndexPath:offersTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
}
```

This gives you the selected `OffersBoughtCellTableViewCell`

Comment: @Shrikant Kankatti I updated the answer using information that given by you in other answer's comment

Comment: i followed as Jogendra.Com was saying ..but now facing ...values are showing temporarily in redeemOfferService method.. when i am scrolling then updated values are not showing its showing from cellforrowattindexpath how to fix this?

Comment: You should change your celForRowAtIndexPath method. When you scrolled, all cells are reused and updated with cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I don't know your updating conditions. So my offer is keep an array of objects which contains your first values. Then when you update your cell, update your object's values. Meanwhile, you should use this object in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method when you load your data to cell.